# how to redirect t o a page with jquery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is simple question. i want to redirect to another page after success in ajax. my code is

```
if (page != 'Theatres') {
    $('.hexagon').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url("dashboard/user/set-home-page-preference") }}',
        data: {
            'page': page
        },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

i want to redirect to a page after the alert data.

Comment: window.location = url;

Comment: Already answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/2869791

Answer (score 1):

Just use `window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";` in the success section

see [How can I make a page redirect using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-page-redirect-using-jquery)